# Surface Area Problem of cube

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am looking for some help with the following problem. I see that the large cube has the following surface area

$$20\times20\times6=2400$$

But what is the surface area of the cut out? one face of it is,

$$10\times10$$

But since the cut out goes all the way through, should i factor in the dimension $20$?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a hole. So area of $4$ faces is not impacted and that remains $ = 4 \times 20^2$.

Now the two faces where square is cut out you have surface area of $10^2$ removed from the original cube on each face but you have 4 sides added inside the cut out with surface area of each $ = 20 \times 10$.

So total surface area of $10$ faces $ = 4 \times 20^2 + 2 \times (20^2 - 10^2) + 4 \times 20 \times 10 = 3000$.

Comment: and what does this equal??

Comment: so is 2800 incorrect?

Comment: @user123 As we count all faces, we are talking about 10 faces. So we need to add area of all 10 faces. That comes to 3000.

Answer (score 0):

You just subtract 2(10cm)$^2$ from the original surface area.

Comment: so what are the total dimensons then?

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the question. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: $(20\times20)\times 4+(20\times20-10\times10)\times 2+(20\times10)\times 4$

Comment: @Eigenvector you only subtract 200?

Comment: Yes assuming that the hole pushes through the other side. The question is about surface area. You'll have two square faces missing 100cm$^2$ of their original area.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the two sides with the hole cut through them will be $(20cm\times20cm)-(10cm\times10cm)$, while the four faces with no hole will have areas $20cm\times20cm$. One thing to note however, is that the inside of the cube is now exposed, so there will be four additional faces with dimensions $10cm\times20cm$. Thus, the total surface area is $4\times(20cm\times20cm)+2\times((20cm\times20cm)-(10cm\times10cm))+4\times(10cm\times20cm)=3000cm^2$.

Comment: could you show the complete workings?